# How to set onclick views dinamically in Android?

Tags: android, onclick

this a program for a musical instrument. I have 10 keys(buttons) for each sound, and a different media player associated to it. I've created a method for each key, but as you can see, the code is always the same; the only thing that changes is the media player...This works fine, but i'm asking if there is a better way to do this, something more dynamic?

```
 public void one() {
    first = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.dokey);
    first.start();
    first.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer play) {
            play.release();
        }
    });
}



  @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v==key1){   //key1 is the button
        one();            
    }
    //and so on...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing too much of your code, I think you could extract the clicklistener and do something like this:

```
private class OnKeyClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {

    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;

    public OnKeyClickListener(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        mMediaPlayer = mediaPlayer;
    }

    @Override public void onClick(View view) {
        /// do the thing
    }
}
```

And than add that to the keys:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer1 = new MediaPlayer(); // mediaplayer for key 1
key1.setOnClickListener(new OnKeyClickListener(mediaPlayer1));

MediaPlayer mediaPlayer2 = new MediaPlayer(); // mediaplayer for key 2
key2.setOnClickListener(new OnKeyClickListener(mediaPlayer2));
```

**EDIT 1:**
Alternatively, you could add the mediaplayer as the tag for the View.

```
key1.setTag(mediaplayer1);
```

And then in onClick get the clicked views tag and cast that to a mediaplayer.

```
onClick(View v) {
    Mediaplayer mediaplayer = (MediaPlayer) v.getTag();
}
```

Comment: I don't know if get it; this means that i just need one media player? Do you need to see more code?

Comment: No, you make every mediaplayer like you already have, and you pass that to your click listeners. So every key has it's own instance of the OnKeyClickListener with every one their own mediaplayer passed along to it.

Comment: thanks, i'll go for the alternative, that sould work